# Is 'I am glad to hear that' very formal or informal phrase?

Tags: phrases, expressions, formality

I said this to one professor when she expressed about her current research work. Later, I realized that that phrase could be very informal.

Comment: It's somewhere in the middle, edging slightly towards formal.

Comment: She did what...??

Comment: @satnam It was written in an email. ( I should have mentioned it 'responded' )

Comment: @Clare She just mentioned in an email about her new research work. She asked me some questions related to the research too. I shall use _I'm happy to hear that_ from now on.

Comment: There's really no difference between "I'm glad to hear that" and "I'm happy to hear that" imo except "glad" is more common.

Comment: This probably depends on local usage. In my neck of the woods (Midwestern US academia) it would be perfectly appropriate in the circumstances you describe; the lack of contraction (*I am* instead of *I'm*) makes it a bit formal-sounding. But I can imagine that the Queen of England might have a different take on it.

Comment: The question shouldn’t be on whether it’s formal or informal. Ask yourself ***why*** she chose to tell you about her work.  It probably wasn’t so you could feel happy about it.  She was probably telling you about so you would be ***interested*** in her work.

Comment: To elaborate on Jim's comment, there is nothing inherently informal about the wording used, but there are many reasons to doubt that this was an appropriate reaction to a professor's communication about her research. Explaining why this might be so, would, however, be outside the scope of this site.

Answer (score 2):

It could be either, but it might edge slightly towards "formal". This expression is usually used by polite and well-educated people. This is backed up by some websites.

> According to [Grammarhow - professional ways to say "I'm glad to hear that"](https://grammarhow.com/professional-ways-to-say-im-glad-to-hear-that/):
>
> > “I'm glad to hear that” is not informal. It can work in both professional and non-professional circumstances.

> According to [grammarhow - good to hear vs glad to hear](https://grammarhow.com/good-to-hear-vs-glad-to-hear/)
>
> > Glad to hear should be used when speaking on a more personal note, as “glad” is a feeling that we can have towards someone.

Noting this, we can deduce that it is better to use "good to hear", especially on the formal side.

Answer (score 0):

It's formal enough:

> “I’m glad to hear that the EU is moving in that direction,” says Barnes.

> Stewart McDonald, the SNP MP for Glasgow South, said: “I’m glad to hear that this has been withdrawn – quite why they thought this would go down well is beyond me.

These both are from MP's or from similar politics environment.

https://lengusa.com/sentence-examples/glad%20to%20hear%20that

Answer (score -3):

Yes, it's informal. You could consider saying 'I am very pleased to hear that', or 'Congratulations! Very well done', or 'That's fantastic to hear!' or 'That's very impressive considering the minimal time you've had to do it' or 'That's impressive indeed'.

Honestly, I would not worry about it. You have said something nice to this person, so she has no right to become offended just because it was worded informally. I'm sure she won't, though.

As it is, you were very kind indeed to compliment the professor. I'm glad to hear it!

Comment: It might not be the most formal way of expressing that idea, but it's not informal. Something like "props" or "yay" or "so chuffed for you" would be clearly informal ways of expressing pleasure, praise, or happiness at something. Of your alternatives, "that's fantastic" or "Congratulations" aren't very formal either, although suitable for most contexts.